# Parsing a MAC address with python

Tags: python, string, mac-address

How can I convert a hex value "0000.0012.13a4" into "00:00:00:12:13:A4"?

Comment: `str.upper()`??

Comment: @Shadow notice period vs colon

Answer (score 1):

```
text = '0000.0012.13a4'
text = text.replace('.', '').upper()   # a little pre-processing

# chunk into groups of 2 and re-join
out = ':'.join([text[i : i + 2] for i in range(0, len(text), 2)])   
print(out)
```

---

```
00:00:00:12:13:A4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

old_string = "0000.0012.13a4"

new_string = ':'.join(s for s in re.split(r"(\w{2})", old_string.upper()) if s.isalnum())

print(new_string)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
00:00:00:12:13:A4
>
```

Without modification, this approach can handle some other MAC formats that you might run into like, `"00-00-00-12-13-a4"`

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
import re
hx = '0000.0012.13a4'.replace('.','')
print(':'.join(re.findall('..', hx)))

Output: 00:00:00:12:13:a4
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a pretty simple three step solution:

### First we strip those pesky periods.

```
step1 = hexStrBad.replace('.','')
```

### Then, if the formatting is consistent:

```
step2 = step1[0:2] + ':' + step1[2:4] + ':' + step1[4:6] + ':' + step1[6:8] + ':' + step1[8:10] + ':' + step1[10:12]
step3 = step2.upper()
```

It's not the prettiest, but it will do what you need!

Comment: But your approach is giving me something like this 00:00:.0:01:2.:13

Comment: Apologies, Try again - I misused the strip() method when the correct method was replace. I have confirmed it working now!

Comment: @chaitanya Definitely _not_ what you need. Don't hardcode ranges like this, it's bad practice.